# Find all the user defined public synonyms in a database

Tags: database, oracle

i want to find all the user defined public synonyms but ALL_SYNONYMS is returning all synonyms created by oracle and users how to filter only user created synonyms from them

Comment: use `where owner IN ('SCHEMA_USER1','SCHEMA_USER2')` etc or query from `user_synonyms` while logged in as the schema user.

Comment: when i am using following query : SELECT * from USER_SYNONYMS where OWNER='PUBLIC' its returning an error stating that owner invalid identifier

Comment: There's no OWNER in USER_SYNONYMS, @Kaushik (but there is in ALL_SYNONYMS, if you meant that).

Comment: Yes, @Littlefoot and Jaya, I meant the condition for `ALL_SYNONYMS`. The other option is If you are logged in as a particular user, then you may simply query `user_synonyms` without the where clause for owner.

Comment: I want to find out all the user defined public synonyms in the data base so how can i do that can u breef it more @KaushikNayak

Answer (score 2):

You may use any of these options.

If you know the names of the users who created the synonyms.

```
select * from all_synonyms where owner IN ('SCHEMA_USER1','SCHEMA_USER2');
```

If you are logged in as a particular user, then this will show all the synonymns 
private to the user.

```
select * from user_synonyms;
```

If you are looking for only public synonyms, this query may be close to what you are looking for.

```
select * from all_synonyms where owner ='PUBLIC'
```

This would show synonyms on tables owned by `system, sys` etc.

You may exclude them using

```
select * from all_synonyms where owner ='PUBLIC' and 
table_owner not IN ( 'SYS','SYSTEM') ;
```

Comment: I have created a public synonym and ran the query is should show the count of public synonym is 1 but its showing the expected output because there are more number of owner not only sys.so under what owner will the public synonym created by me will go

Thanks
@KaushikNayak